# In the C standard library, is there a similar function to `fcntl()`?

Tags: c, linux

In Linux API, `fcntl()` can be very useful to get or set file descriptor flags, file status flags, and other properties.

In the C standard library, is there a similar function to `fcntl()` which can get or set the properties of a `FILE` object, and its underlying file descriptor flags, file status flags, and other properties?

Answer (score 4):

No. That's because, in the ISO C standard, `FILE`-based processing is the lowest level API specified. It's not necessary that file descriptors (and the other things you mention) even *exist.*

How it's handled "under the covers" is totally dependent on the implementation, so you have to revert to implementation-specific stuff if you want access to its information.

The POSIX standard actually mandates the underlying mechanisms and many C implementations also support POSIX but it's by no means required by ISO C, the one true C standard :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have `fcntl` in the first place, then you should also have two other functions which let you go back and forth between bare file descriptors and FILE objects: [`fileno`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno) and [`fdopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen).  None of these functions are specified by ISO C (hence they are not part of *the* standard C library) but they are all included in the POSIX standard (which defines most of what it means to be a "Unix"), so if you have one of them you can expect to have all three.  The header `fcntl.h` is also part of that standard.